# Android AIDL: Project crash after change code to kotlin from java

Tags: android, crash, kotlin, aidl

These are the link of my project
[AIDL-Client](https://github.com/fhlkm/AIDLClient), [AIDL-Server](https://github.com/fhlkm/AIDLServer).
Steps:

1. Please install both apks.
2. Then click "BIND Device button"
3. "**IBindDeviceCallback: deviceName: tpd  deviceBrand: loop**" is print in client project
4. change  "AIDLService.java" to "AIDLService.kt"in AIDL-Server project then install apk.
5. Then click "BIND Device button"" of AIDL-server project

you will find the crash.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter deviceCertifcate
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1697)
                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
                                                                at com.loop.ILoopService$Stub$Proxy.bindDevice(ILoopService.java:88)
                                                                at com.client.MainActivity$mServiceConnection$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.kt:53)
                                                                at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1516)
                                                                at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1544)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

It looks like android/kotlin's problem rather than mine.

Any idea about this crash, how to fix it in kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the exception looks like it is coming from Android is because it is being passed between processes.

On `MainActivity.kt` line 53 in your client code, you pass null to `bindDevice` for the `deviceCertificate` `byte[]`. The exception is telling you that this cannot be null.

When you convert the service from Java to Kotlin, it treats the method parameter as non-null by default, `deviceCertifcate: ByteArray`.  If you tell Kotlin that this parameter can be null, it will not crash. This is acheived by declaring the type with a `?`, i.e. `deviceCertifcate: ByteArray?`.

For more information see [the Kotlin docs on Null-Safety.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

In a normal Kotlin app, this wouldn't even compile, but since this goes across process boundaries via AIDL, the compiler can't catch this issue.